# Change a property of an existing object. gtk3 + python

Tags: python, gtk3

I want to change objects property when needed.

How can i "point" to the object ?
How can i change the objects property while the app is open/active?

An example (this is code is not correct)

```
builder = Gtk.Builder()
object = builder.get_object('object_to_change')
object.set_property()
```

[EDIT]
I got it almost working...
It doesn't update (sensitive option- if it is active or not)
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-sensitive

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find online, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 3):

You have to give Gtk.Builder data for it to load, then you can get the objects as usual. Gtk.Builder can load data in a few different ways, I recommend you take a look at the [documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Builder.html#Gtk.Builder).

```py
# Load from a file
builder = Gtk.Builder.new_from_file('window.ui')
# Get the object by id (name)
label = builder.get_object('label')
# Do anything you want with label
label.set_property('wrap', True)
```

If you haven't already I also recommend you read [The Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Chapter 21 (Glade and Gtk.Builder) covers that.

Comment: Now i know what i did wrong...i will take a closer look (i already looked and the documentations/tutorials you linked but i had a hard time understanding)
Thank you very much for you help and time !